# How to modify the array of objects (original form to new form) with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting the data as array of objects which is in key value form. Like below:

```
"data": [
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuth",
      "count": 41
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthEmpty",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthSQL",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "Unsecured",
      "count": 75
    }
  ]
```

But my idea here to change its original form and make it as below, means the key "count" should be "value" and the key "groupBy" should be "name". How to change it programatically using typescript or javascript:

```
data:[
            {value:41, name:'InvalidAuth'},
            {value:75, name:'InvalidAuthEmpty'},
            {value:75, name:'InvalidAuthSQL'},
            {value:75, name:'Unsecured'}
]
```

As the original form is not working with e-charts. e-charts only works with value and name form only.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to get a copy of the original array, with the desired property names:

```js
const data = [
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuth",
      "count": 41
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthEmpty",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthSQL",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "Unsecured",
      "count": 75
    }
  ];
  
  const data2 = data.map(x => ({
    value: x.count,
    name: x.groupBy
  }));
  
  console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `map` and `destructuring`

```js
const data = [{"groupBy": "InvalidAuth","count": 41},{"groupBy": "InvalidAuthEmpty","count": 75},{"groupBy": "InvalidAuthSQL","count": 75},{"groupBy": "Unsecured","count": 75}]
  
let op = data.map(({count:value,groupBy:name}) => ({name,value}))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: why did you not use `data` directly? why encapsulate it into obj? would be fine without it.

Comment: @its4zahoor it's called [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it's not encapsulating it in object, yeah that matters of choice even if you do it directly then also it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your problem:

```
let newData = [];
for(let thisData of data){
  newData.push({
    value: thisData.count,
    name: thisData.groupBy,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just iterate over `data array`  and rename existing keys and delete older ones.

```js
var data= [
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuth",
      "count": 41
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthEmpty",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "InvalidAuthSQL",
      "count": 75
    },
    {
      "groupBy": "Unsecured",
      "count": 75
    }
  ]
  
   data.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.name =elem.groupBy;
    elem.value =elem.count;
    delete elem['groupBy'];
    delete elem['count'];
  });
  console.log(data);
```